# How to get value to one html page to another in Django?

Tags: python, django

I just began to work with Django and I would like to create a submit form in a html form that communicates with another html page.

Page1.html : Submit form, let's suppose I type "Hello world" then I click on submit, I'm redirected to page2.html

Page2.html : Thanks to the Get request Page2.html display "Hello World" because the page2 has been loaded from page1

In page1 I use this form :

```
<form type="get" action="/page2" style="margin: 0">
<input  id="search_box" type="text" name="search_box"  placeholder="Search..." >
<button id="search_submit" type="submit" >Search</button>
```

In Views.py I have this function :

```
def page2(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        search_query = request.GET.get('search_box', None)
        return render(request, 'interface/recherche.html', locals())
```

But I don't know how to display how the word that has been typed in page1 in page2, thank you very much for your answer :)

Comment: `type="get"` doesn't do anything. `method="get"` is what you want (it's the default so that's why this works anyway..)

Answer (score 3):

Sending entire local variables to the template may be dangerous and insecure, as well as unnecessary so instead of passing `locals()`, you can either pass the entire querystring using `request.GET` or just the value keyed with `search_box`:

```
return render(request, "interface/recherche.html", request.GET)
```

or

```
return render(request, "interface/recherche.html", {"search_box": search_query})
```

and you can print out the value in `recherche.html` like `{{ search_box }}`.

You can test it out by typing something like `/page2?search_box=text` into the address bar of your browser. The page should display `text`.